# Is there a way to disconnect the laptop battery in Arch Linux?

Tags: laptop, arch-linux, battery, battery-life

I use Arch Linux on a laptop. To make the battery last longer, I wanna be able to disconnect it entirely to minimize idle leakage and little recharges when the battery level drops. I also want to be able to connect it back for when I need to unplug and move which happens often, then disconnect it again right after.

Is there a way to disconnect the battery from inside Arch Linux?

Comment: Without rewriting the system controller firmware, I doubt this would be possible for _any_ operating system. I don't think the OS has this level of control over the battery. This is one of the reason Macs get such excellent battery life, Apple does control the hardware and software and can integrate it properly, but I doubt this level of integration exists for PCs.

Comment: See if your laptop BIOS (UEFI) supports Battery Threshold management and if your Linux has an App to manage the battery. That is the only practical way I know to manage batteries. Many modern laptops have this feature.

Comment: It depends on the laptop -- on some, there is a steady drain even if the system is entirely shut down, perhaps due to charge equalizers working directly on each cell. On those, the only feasible way to fix the issue is to remove the battery when not in use. Even a switch in series with the battery would not completely stop the drain, since the equalizer connects across *each cell*.